# Linked list - Insertion of a node at the end of the list in C

Tags: c, data-structures

This is the code for insertion of a node at the end. I am not getting any error while running but it shows that the programme has stopped working. please tell me where i have messed it here?

```
enter code here

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct node{
int data;
struct node* next;
};

struct node* head;

void Insert(int data)
{
    struct node* temp, *temp2;
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp2 = head;
    while(temp2 != NULL)
    {
        temp2 = temp2->next;
    }
    temp2->next = temp;
    temp->next = NULL;

}
void print()
{
    struct node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d", temp->data);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
int main()
{
    head = NULL;
    Insert(1);
    Insert(2);
    Insert(3);
    Insert(4);
    Insert(5);
    print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while(temp2 != NULL) { temp2 = temp2->next} temp2->next = temp;` What do you think the value of `temp2` will be after the `while` loop finishes? Suggest you use a debugger to help you debug problems on your own before posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(temp2 != NULL)
{
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
temp2->next = temp;
```

After this loop `temp2` is always `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps instead of

```
while(temp2 != NULL)
{
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
```

you meant to write

```
while(temp2->next != NULL)
{
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
```

Also, your head variable is always NULL. You must assign a value such as with an allocation in main:

```
int main()
{
    head = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ...
}
```

Also, your print function does not iterate through the list so there is an infinite while loop, instead try:

```
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    printf("%d", temp->data);
    temp = temp->next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After this loop in the function

```
while(temp2 != NULL)
{
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}
```

pointer `temp2` will be equal to `NULL` because it is the condition when the loop will be interrupted.

Thus this statement after the loop

```
temp2->next = temp;
```

results in undefined behaviour of the function.

The function can be written much simpler

```
void Insert( int data )
{
    struct node *temp = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );

    if ( temp != NULL )
    {
        temp->data = data;
        temp->next = NULL;

        struct node **last = &head;

        while ( *last != NULL ) last = &( *last )->next;

        *last = temp;
    }
}
```

Pay attention that you forgot one statement in the function print. It should look like

```
void print( void )
           ^^^^^^
{
    struct node* temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", temp->data);
                ^^^
        temp = temp->next;
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And instead of the while loop I would use the following for loop

```
void print( void )
{
    for ( struct node *temp = head; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next )
    {
        printf( "%d ", temp->data );
    }
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

Comment: thanks again for the answer. can you tell me what i am doing wrong in my void Insert function by using my approach except for this  while(temp2 != NULL)
{
    temp2 = temp2->next;
}. if possible can you give the solution.

Comment: @VishalBarkakati It is the main problem. You could splict the function body in two parts. The first one checks whether the head is equal to NULL. And the second one uses loop while ( temp2->next != NULL )